# How to enable B frame encoding in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediacodec, video-encoding

Now, I'm using mediaCodec to encode the video and want to enable the B frame during encoding in Android. The configs of MediaFormat are as follows:

```
format.setInteger("profile", 8);
format.setInteger("level", 0x200);
format.setInteger("max-bframes", 5);

mediacodec = createByCodecName(properties.codecName);
mediaCodec.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
```

But, I can't get the B frame. Why? Who can help me?

Comment: What version of Android are you testing it on?

Comment: Both Android 9 and Android 11.

Answer (score 0):

The `KEY_MAX_B_FRAMES` key was added to `MediaFormat` in API level 29.

So devices running Android 9 and earlier are not expected to recognize this field. As for Android 10 and up the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat#KEY_MAX_B_FRAMES) says:

> Note that non-zero value does not guarantee B frames; it's up to the encoder to decide.

In other words this field doesn't force the encoder to use B frames only sets the upper bound in case it will.